# different proofs of the fact that compact riemann surface has a non-trivial meromorphic function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I would have like to have a list of different proofs of the fact that compact riemann surface has a non-trivial meromorphic function.This is certainly one of the main results of compact riemann surface.Some proofs use sheaves and some more elementary just using forms and some using riemann-roch theorem.

Comment: Related http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19649/physical-construction-of-nonconstant-meromorphic-functions-on-compact-riemann?rq=1